# How can I validate different schemas based on an enumerated property value with AJV?

Tags: validation, jsonschema, ajv

I need to validate a json document depending the value in one of the properties, specifically an `enum` property.

This is the JSON document to be validated:

```
{
    "req": {
        "user": "",
        "company": "",
        "dept": "",
        "class": "",
        "reqType": "account"
    }
}
```

The `reqType` can take different values like `account`, `dept`, and `class` based on the enumerated values.

I have tried using `anyOf` for the same but it does not validate correctly.

For example, I have tried the schema below:

```
{
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {},
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "req": {
            "$id": "/properties/req",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "user": {
                    "$id": "/properties/req/properties/user",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The User Schema ",
                    "default": "",
                    "examples": [
                        "a"
                    ]
                },
                "company": {
                    "$id": "/properties/req/properties/company",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The Company Schema ",
                    "default": "",
                    "examples": [
                        "b"
                    ]
                },
                "dept": {
                    "$id": "/properties/req/properties/dept",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The Dept Schema ",
                    "default": "",
                    "examples": [
                        "c"
                    ]
                },
                "class": {
                    "$id": "/properties/req/properties/class",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The Class Schema ",
                    "default": "",
                    "examples": [
                        "d"
                    ]
                },
                "reqType": {
                    "$id": "/properties/req/properties/reqType",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The Reqtype Schema ",
                    "default": "",
                    "examples": [
                        "account"
                    ],
                    "enum": [
                        "account",
                        "dept",
                        "class"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "reqType"
            ],
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "reqType": {
                            "enum": [
                                "account"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "user",
                        "company"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "reqType": {
                            "enum": [
                                "dept"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "dept"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "req"
    ]
}
```

This seems to work fine when it meets all of the conditions but when I check the failing case it throws an error for others as follows:

```
[
  {
    keyword: 'required',
    dataPath: '.req',
    schemaPath: '#/properties/req/anyOf/0/required',
    params: {
      missingProperty: 'user'
    },
    message: 'should have required property \'user\'',
    schema: ['user', 'company'],
    parentSchema: {
      properties: [Object],
      required: [Array]
    },
    data: {
      company: 'b', dept: 'c', class: 'd', reqType: 'account'
    }
  },
  {
    keyword: 'enum',
    dataPath: '.req.reqType',
    schemaPath: '#/properties/req/anyOf/1/properties/reqType/enum',
    params: {
      allowedValues: [Array]
    },
    message: 'should be equal to one of the allowed values',
    schema: ['dept'],
    parentSchema: {
      enum: [Array]
    },
    data: 'account'
  },
  {
    keyword: 'anyOf',
    dataPath: '.req',
    schemaPath: '#/properties/req/anyOf',
    params: {},
    message: 'should match some schema in anyOf',
    schema: [
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ],
    parentSchema: {
      '$id': '/properties/req',
      type: 'object',
      properties: [Object],
      required: [Array],
      anyOf: [Array]
    },
    data: {
      company: 'b', dept: 'c', class: 'd', reqType: 'account'
    }
  }
]
```

I expected to get an error for the first and should have validated the 2nd case. Instead it says it did not get the enum value. Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it right. The `anyOf` keyword means that one or more of the given schemas must be valid.

It checks the first and finds that the `enum` keyword passes, but the `required` keyword fails. Therefore, this schema fails.

So, it moves on to the next schema and finds that the `enum` keyword fails and the `required` keyword passes. Therefore, this schema fails too.

`anyOf` did not find a valid schema, so it fails and reports that neither schema passes validation.

You see, `anyOf` doesn't know that `enum` has a special meaning in this schema. Both schemas have one keyword that passes and one that fails. To `anyOf`, they are the same.

---

Here is an alternative that can give you slightly better error messaging. The error messages still end up being quite cryptic, but they are focused where the problem really is.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "req": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "reqType": { "enum": ["account", "dept", "class"] }
      },
      "required": ["reqType"],
      "allOf": [
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "not": {
                "properties": {
                  "reqType": { "enum": ["account"] }
                }
              }
            },
            { "required": ["user", "company"] }
          ]
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "not": {
                "properties": {
                  "reqType": { "enum": ["dept"] }
                }
              }
            },
            { "required": ["dept"] }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": ["req"]
}
```